# Turning off NSPredicateEditor animation

Tags: macos, nspredicateeditor

By default, adding and removing rows from NSPredicateEditor is done with animation.  I'd like to get rid of that animation, or at least set its duration to zero, but have had no luck.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a good way, but it works:

Subclass `NSPredicateEditor` and add:

```
- (BOOL)animationShouldStart:(NSAnimation *)animation {
    animation.duration = 0.0;
    return YES;
}
```

This method is part of the `NSAnimationDelegate` protocol, which is apparently used by `NSPredicateEditor`. Please keep in mind, that this might break at any time. Lets hope Apple adds an official way to disable animations.